# Graph-Finding unreachable nodes in undirected graph using Depth First Search

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

I have a undirected graph (may be disconnected graph).
I need to find Number of unreachable nodes for a given node.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> graph[1000];
bool visited[1000];
int count=0;

void dfs(int s)
{
  count=count+1;
  visited[s]=true;
  for(int i=0;i<graph[s].size();i++)
    if(visited[graph[s][i]]==false)
      dfs(i);
}

int main()
{
  int n,m;
  cin>>n>>m;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    int x,y; 
    cin>>x>>y;
    graph[x].push_back(y);
    graph[y].push_back(x);
  }
  int k;
  cin>>k;
  dfs(k);

  cout<<n-count;
}
```

Initially the graph has n nodes. After DFS process, for the particular node k ,dfs(k) finds number of nodes connected with k.
So the unreachable nodes can be calculated by n-count.

But this codes shows an error that says **reference to 'count' is ambiguous**.
What is the problem? Did I make any mistake in DFS recursive method?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't pollute namespaces. `using namespace std;` is the culprit. Read [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ library there is `count` function template - in `algorithm` header (which was included by `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` directive), you can resolve your problem by adding `::` before `count` in `dfs` and `main` function.

```
  ::count= ::count+1;
```

and

```
  cout<<n-::count;
```